# Genexus Create contact in address book

Tags: genexus, genexus-sd

How can I, in genexus, use a tap event to create a contact in the mobile address book that works for android and iOS?

Comment: what have you got so far? questions should include some research effort

Comment: Im already try this http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?HowTo%3A+Using+AddContact+From+AddressBook+in+SDAPIs+for+Smart+Devices, but there is no show how add the mobile phone during the event execution.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided (http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?HowTo%3A+Using+AddContact+From+AddressBook+in+SDAPIs+for+Smart+Devices) has everithing you need to address you question.
What is your concern about this issue?

Comment: Hi Paulo, yes I got do using the wiki but when I tap in the AddContact the behavior was compose a new contact but is wait to user press save...  the question is if is possible dont need wait the user press save, I want create the contact in silent mode this is I cannot do until now, its possible ?

Comment: No, I don´t think it´s possible. The owner of the smartphone must "confirm" the insertion.

Comment: Unfortunatelly I think it also :-)